# Indexes in many-to-many mysql workbench generated

Tags: mysql, indexing, many-to-many, query-optimization, mysql-workbench

I have a a schema of 2 tables linked by a many-to-many relationship (so there is a third table), the tables' code has been generated by MySQL WorkBench.

here is the code :

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Publication`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Publication` (
  `idPublication` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `Date` YEAR NOT NULL,
  `Type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Conference` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPublication`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Author`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Author` (
  `idAuthor` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAuthor`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Author_has_Publication`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Author_has_Publication` (
  `Author_idAuthor` INT NOT NULL,
  `Publication_idPublication` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Author_idAuthor`, `Publication_idPublication`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Author_has_Publication_Author`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Author_idAuthor`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Author` (`idAuthor`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Author_has_Publication_Publication1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Publication_idPublication`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Publication` (`idPublication`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I have a list of query (return the top 10 most prolific authors, return the number of each type of publication, find all publication of author X at year X, find author with the most publication with the word "Data" in the title, etc). All of these are done and working. But as the db is pretty huge (xml file of 49 millions lines), I am asked to see what queries can be optimized with indexes.

So I would like to know if MySQL workbench generate automaticaly Indexes to handle the relation ? and what type of query can be optimized with which index ?

Comment: No, MySQL workbench does not generate anything automatically, since it is only a client of MySQL. MySQL server does generate indexes implicitly on foreign keys, if none exists. Indexes speed up queries that join, filter, sort, or group records based on fields that are in the index. There are entire books written on how to use indexes, so it is rather difficult to give you a generic response in a few paragraphs. Learn how to use the explain statement and how to interpret its output to help you understanding the index usage of your queries.

Comment: Ok thx so i have to build my own index, damn that's not gonna be a piece of cake ....

Comment: The foreign key relationships are covered with indexes. You only have to create those indexes that are not based on the fields in a foreign key, or extend existing indexes to cover more scenarios.

Comment: so mysql workbench generates index as i got foreign keys no ?

Comment: Again: MySQL workbench does not generate anything automatically. It's your front-end. MySQL server generates the indexes on foreign keys.